# Simple SQL query with join same table and get value from 2 row in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data

[image: Sample table data]

I need result of query like this:

[image: Result set]

With this query :

```
select 
    early.sensor,
    early.event,
    late.value - early.value as value
from data_table as early 
inner join data_table as late on 
    early.sensor=late.sensor and early.event=late.event
where late.event_date > early.event_date;
```

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: What are the rules to get the result .. how are the two lines for subtraction selected?

Comment: Are you looking for all rows where sensor + event occurs twice? And from these you take the newer value minus the older value? Have I guessed right? Can it happen that a sensor + event pair occurs more than twice? What to do then?

Comment: Question is that we need value from most recently row per sensor and event minus first row before most reenly row. For example: row one has value -1 and row two has value 2 for same sensor and event, result is -1-2=-3. This is corect: "And from these you take the newer value minus the older value?", answer for this question is YES :"Can it happen that a sensor + event pair occurs more than twice? What to do then?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the input table is called "data_table" and the fourth column in it is called event_date, then something like this should do it:

```
select
    early.sensor,
    early.event,
    late.value - early.value as value
from
    data_table as early
    inner join data_table as late on 
        early.sensor=late.sensor
        and early.event=late.event
where
    late.event_date > early.event_date;
```

But if there are more than two values (as @Thorston Kettner asks), then you will need some more complex logic.

Comment: I do not get any value in result panel with this query.